# Docker y RMI problema puerto

Tags: java, docker, puertos

Se intenta `Dockerizar` una aplicación servidor en Java, a su vez tenemos dos aplicaciones cliente, una interfaz gráfica (GUI) y un emulador.

- Efectos deseados:

  1. El emulador corre sobre una máquina anfitrión y se comunica con la
     aplicación servidor corriendo en un contenedor Docker mediante dos
     puertos `10008 – 10009` mediante `protocolo TCP`.
  2. La interfaz gráfica corre sobre una máquina anfitrión y se comunica
     con la aplicación servidor corriendo en un contenedor Docker por un
     puerto `40031` por `RMI (Invocación de Métodos Remota)`.

El primer caso funciona sin problemas, sólo tenemos que arrancar la aplicación exponiendo los puertos `10008 y 10009`.

- En el segundo caso surgen problemas y no se logra dar funcionamiento.

Toda la informacion encontrada sobre RMI es sobre intentar monitorizar una aplicación con JMX, el cual, no es el caso, la solución dada es la de añadir ciertas flags en el arranque, ejemplo:

```
JMX_PORT=9010
HOST="0.0.0.0"
java \
-Dsun.management.jmxremote.level=FINEST \
-Dsun.management.jmxremote.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler \
-Djava.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=$HOST \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$HOST \
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 \
-jar /opt/app/app.jar
```

En este caso la solución no da el resultado esperado.

Cuando la aplicación servidor arranca en docker levanta RMI en el puerto `40031` correctamente, también se observa como cliente y servidor establecen conexión `TCP` pero aun así no funciona.
Cabe decir que arrancando todo en local el funcionamiento es el correcto.

¿Alguien se ha enfrentado a un problema similar o se puede guiarme un poco sobre este problema?

Fuentes ya revisadas para intentar dar solución al problema:

[Github.com](https://github.com/cstroe/java-jmx-in-docker-sample-app)

[Adambien.blog](http://adambien.blog/roller/abien/entry/how_to_establish_jmx_connection)

Comment: Según la fuente que colocas te falta el parámetro `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` o también puede ser `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true` creo que te los has saltado porque viste que no tiene un valor, pero se pude usar de las 2 formas, comentas si eso resuelve tu problema.

Comment: Un punto a tener en cuenta es que JMX y RMI no es lo mismo, JMX se comunica a través de RMI para obtener las métricas, puedes expone tus propios MBeans para ejecutar procesos Remotos, esto no es recomendable porque RMI no es un protocolo amigable y flexible para implementas todo un sistema, además estarías limitado al lenguaje Java ya que no estoy claro si es posible invocar con otros lenguajes.

Comment: Es preferible un servicio WSDL ó REST sobre RMI para la comunicación Remota, además la idea de utilizar Docker es poder escalar servicios y con RMI eso es más una tarea titánica ya que está diseñado para comunicarse sobre una sola conexión, estos son unos ejemplo de como se implantan los servicios https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remote-method-invocation-in-java/ y http://laurel.datsi.fi.upm.es/~ssoo/SD.dir/practicas/guiarmi.html

Comment: RMI es una tecnologia Java, y solo sirve para comunicación de aplicaciones en este lenguaje. Y cuando ambas maquinas son java utilizar RMI en vez de otro protocolo como REST tiene muchas ventajas. El unico problema es que desaparece a partir de java 8 creo

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, la aplicación ya está montada y esta trabajando sobre RMI perfectamente, cambiar la comunicación no se una opción.Como bien dices esta tecnología sólo funciona con Java. Esas flags estan pensadas para JMX y este no es el caso, no funciona al ponerlas. Pareceque docker y RMI no son muy amigos, RMI server está corriendo perfectamente dentro del contenedor pero no consigo acceder desde fuera, el mapeo no funciona. Alguna idea? @RobertoEMoran